# Prove that $||f||_2 \le \sqrt{2 \pi} ||f || _{\infty}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, fourier-series, lp-spaces

Let $||f||_2=\sqrt{\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f^2(x) dx}$

$||f||_{\infty}=\sup \{ |f(x)| \mid x \in [-\pi,\pi]\}$.

Suppose $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ an in the space of piecewise continuous functions with period $2 \pi$.

Prove that $||f||_2 \le \sqrt{2 \pi} ||f || _{\infty}$.

$\textbf{My Attempt:}$

I know that $a_0 = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x) dx$

It seems that I could try using something like this, $2 \pi a_0 = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x) dx$ so  $\sqrt{2 \pi} \sqrt{a_0} = \sqrt{ \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x) dx}$.

Of course I run in to the problem that the values are not necessarily nonnegative.

It seems that using the fourier coefficient $a_0$ would be useful to complete the proof. However, I am having a hard time with this.

Help is appreciated! Thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $|f| \leq \|f\|_\infty$,
$$
  \|f\|_2^2 
  = \int_{-\pi}^\pi |f|^2
  \leq \int_{-\pi}^\pi \|f\|_\infty^2
  = 2\pi \|f\|_\infty^2 .
$$